# csv stored data deleted when writerow() method executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, file, io

I want to read data from CSV file and immediately store them in another CSV file

The problem is whenever I run this function, it deletes all the stored data from the input file (there is no exception).

```
def calculate_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    with open(input_file_name, mode="r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            grades = list(map(int, row[1:]))
            with open(input_file_name, mode="w") as wfile:
                writer = csv.writer(wfile)
                writer.writerow([row[0], mean(grades)])
```

Comment: You're overwriting the same file you're reading as you read it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `output_file_name` to store output data. Instead, you use `input_file_name` to read data, and then write to `input_file_name`.